# xcode build error framework not found

Tags: xcode, swift, ios7, cocoapods

Okay, using xcode7, swift and ios7 target.

I installed cocoapods

I change terminal to my project file folder and ran `pod setup`

Now **Podfile** is in the same directory as my **.xcodeproj** file and loks like this:

```
plaform :ios, '7.0' 
use_frameworks! 
pod 'OAStackView'
```

I change terminal to my project file folder and run `pod install`

Now, if I try build I get:

> Frame not found OAStackView clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Am I supposed to do anything else to get OAStackView working? (I verified the problem also happens wih other pods) I have not yet imported it to any unit or anything, just trying to compile

Comment: are you opening .xcodeproj or workspace. You have to open your project with workspace

Comment: I think this migh be he reason - I will look into it and report back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be opening the `.xcodeproj` instead of opening `.xcworkspace`.
 With **CocoaPods** we have to open `.xcworkspace` file.